# Jquery sending Json to Asp.net Codebehind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

i try to send a json to a aspx site and get the callback, but it won´t work.

When i try this:

Jquery:

```
$( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
    .button()
    .click(function( event ) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType : 'jsonp',
            jsonp : 'jsonp_callback',
            url : 'Entry.aspx/GetString',
            success : function(sqlArray) {
                alert(sqlArray);
            },
            error: Failed
        });

        function Failed(result) {  
              alert("Fail: "+result.status + " " + result.statusText);  
        }   
    });
```

Asp.net:

```
    [WebMethod]
public static string GetString(string tracking_num)
{
    var customer = new data { text="Joe Bloggs"};
    string json = customer.toJson();
    return json;
}
```

i get the Error:

> Fail: 200 OK

When i change the ajax datatyp from "Json" to "Text", the success function will be called, but the alertboxtext is the Html-Code of the aspx site.

Thanks

Comment: I belive the `toJson` function is broken, and not giving a valid json format.

Comment: You are not passing in the `tracking_num` value, so the call to your web method is failing. Since you are not using the param, I'd just remove it. If you need it, you'll have to set `data` in your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Set the content type in the GetString method.

```
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
```

and use dataType:'json' in the ajax call.

Comment: Nothing work:(, but now, i found the problem, the "getString" Method never get called. I have add a "Console.writeline("I am called");" but the Console is empty after press the button.